# Highlighting inconsistency (Tire / ElasticSearch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

I am trying to use Tire (ElasticSearch) with highlighting, but I am experiencing some inconsistencies and I am probably doing something wrong. The problem I got into is that it does not always highlight the possessives for the term I am looking for. Here is the setup:

Indexing:

```
indexes :thesis,              type: 'string',   boost:  2.0,            analyzer: 'snowball',  as: 'index_clean_thesis'
# the 'index_clean_thesis' removes some formatting characters as \t, \r, \n.
```

Query:

```
query { match :thesis, params[:text] }
```

I am querying for the term 'Google'.

Now, I have two test entries in my ElasticSearch index (one has an legit text of one of the entries I want to index, while one has some text I made up for testing purposes). On the big text, I am only getting one instance of "Google's" out of around 14 actual, present. On the test text, I am getting all of them.

Here is one instance from the big text where it doesn't highlight "Google's"

```
Imminent changes to Google’s policies could dramatically lower the
```

Here is the only instance from the big text where it does highlight "Google's"

```
I want to ask about Google's pending Toolbar change.
```

Here is the test text where highlighting works as expected

```
Google's bla is blabla APPLE google is GOOGLE+ blabla facebook bla is yes yes no Google's ononononono tyeyeeyeyye ete pw iepq kw iqpe iwpq google pqiwop qoweo qpwoe qdpw adpw google's ksowoskwo google+
```

I also tried the queries through direct *curl* queries on ElasticSearch but I get the same behavior. Here is the *curl* query I tried:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/postings/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "thesis": "Google"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "thesis": {
        "fragment_size": 40,
        "number_of_fragments": 300
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong that causes this weird behavior.

Comment: Ok so this problem appears on character encodings from UTF-8...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, never mind, I just realized what the problem was - it is a bit ridiculous but I am grateful to the StackOverflow code text editor haha: it made me realize that in the examples that it doesn't highlight, there is actually *a different apostrophe* and probably ElasticSearch doesn't stem it right.

Sorry for the silly post, but maybe someone will find it useful in the future... I have to specify that the data is input from a form and who knows how that weird apostrophe got in. I am going to filter them out at the object save and put the right apostrophe instead.

This was a really hard one to get since my text editors don't seem to show a big difference between those 2 apostrophes...

Thanks,
Vlad